# Using .htaccess to set a sub directory as root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting, root

Is there a way to use htaccess to tell a subdirectory to act as the root for the entire site?

For example, if I had a website under http://localhost/testsite/ and in it's index.php file I had a reference to the stylesheet using the following code..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/layout.css" />
```

Could I then make that load /localhost/testsite/css/layout.css?

To get around this problem, I set up localhost subdomains for each site which although works, is not ideal.

Many thanks.

Comment: Setup a virtual host.

Comment: As cillosis pointed out, this would normally be done in your Apache config for the site. Simply set the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) to the desired folder.

Comment: make sure you have`RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory [L]`

Answer (score 21):

If you want to keep the 'href="/css/layout.css"' part, then yes, you can set up a rewrite rule. You just have to be careful not to redirect anything starting with /testsite (or you'll end up with a loop).

Like (in root .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testsite/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testsite/$1 [QSA,L]
```

There, you will be able to access your layout.css file either from:

http://localhost/testsite/css/layout.css

or

http://localhost/css/layout.css

Answer (score 4):

Sure, all relative URIs (as yours) are relative to the base URI which by default is the URI of the document:

```
http://localhost/testsite/index.php
```

You only need to tell which part to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/layout.css" />
                                             ^
                                             ` see this dot
```

Example:

```
Base URI      ::  http://localhost/testsite/index.php
Relative URI  ::  ./css/layout.css
Result        ::  http://localhost/testsite/css/layout.css
```

If you need to have this  more modular, there are multiple ways to do that. One is to set the base URI explicitly inside the HTML document (see `<base>`).

Another one is to resolve links relatively on the server-side based on the *Request URI* and  your site's root-path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9216978/367456) for an example.