# PHP root with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using 000webhost, which uses a public_html folder in the root folder as the visible root for the site.  In that folder, I have an assets folder with some PHP scripts, and other folders with PHP index pages.  Using `require "/assets/includes/scriptname.php";` does not work, as it tries to find a sibling folder to public_html.  I'm allowed to edit .htaccess to change the root folder relative to the PHP lookup, but I don't know how.

File tree:

```
public_html (within root, but simulated root)
   folder1
      index.php
   folder2
      index.php
   folder3
      index.php
   assets
      subfolder
      subfolder
   index.php
```

In short, how do I make the mentioned code point inside `/public_html/` without explicitly declaring it (preferably as a .htaccess change, as I want my code to be able to be moved to a different host without rewriting anything).

For an answer with the .htaccess rewrite, could you explain how each line of it works?  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `require "/..."` look for a file relative to file system `/`? Unless you `chroot` the script somehow, how is it supposed to work? I'd use relative paths, or set `include_path` to `assets/includes` and then just `require "scriptname.php"`

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413127/using-htaccess-to-set-a-sub-directory-as-root-directory or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost - would it work for my purposes? (most likely the first one)

Comment: `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); require "assets/...";` should be just fine.

Comment: That gives an error that says there's an open_basedir restriction.

Comment: @Firedrake969 The problem with this is that mod_rewrite rewrites the _requests_ and you are using php's `require` which has nothing to do with requests and will not be handled by it

Comment: Ok, any other options that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` does not help you. It is an Apache configuration and it does not affect the behavior of PHP in any way.

The code:

```
require "/assets/includes/scriptname.php"
```

tells PHP to include a file using an absolute path. Using hardcoded absolute paths is not recommended because the code won't work when you move it into another directory or on a different server that has different paths.

The best way to specify the path of an included file is to generate it runtime, starting from the path of the includer. The PHP function [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and the constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) are the helpers here.

Given the sample file structure:

```
public_html
   |
   +- index.php
   |
   +- assets
   |     |
   |     +- somescript.php
   |
   +- includes
         |
         +- header.php
         |
         +- footer.php
```

Let's say you need to include `assets/somescript.php` in `index.php`. Write this in `index.php`:

```
 require __DIR__.'/assets/somescript.php';
```

The magic constant `__DIR__` contains the directory of the file where it is used. For `index.php`, `__DIR__` is set to `'/(...path-to-your-user-directory...)/public_html'`.

If `somescript.php` needs to include `header.php` it should do it like this:

```
require dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/header.php';
```

and so on.

This way you can move the entire application to a different directory, on a different server and even on a different OS and it will still work.

Comment: For your first `require` code, you used `__DIR__`, while for your second, you used dirname(`__DIR__`).  Would it be safe to always just keep it as `__DIR__` or dirname(`__DIR__`)?  If so, which one?  What's the difference?

Comment: In `assets/somescript.php`, `__DIR__` is `'/..../public_html/assets'`. You need to go up one level (to `public_html`) before appending `/includes/header.php`.

Comment: So no matter what the base folder is, using `dirname(__DIR__)` should work?  Even if the base folder isn't named?  (like if it's directly next to public_html rather than in public_html)

Comment: Read the documentation, think a bit about it, do some tests (`echo(__DIR__)`, `echo(dirname(__DIR__))`, `echo(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))`, stuff like that) and suddenly everything will become more clear.

Comment: One thing - using `dirname(__DIR__)` does work for your example in index.php, but doesn't work for your example in somescript.php.  Error is `require(./assets/folder/file.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream`

Comment: EDIT to above comment - was using PHP 5.2.x, so working around with dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).

Comment: Indeed, `__DIR__` was introduced in PHP 5.3. If you can you better switch to PHP 5.4 or newer. 5.2 is [dead for almost 4 years now](http://php.net/eol.php), 5.3 is expired too, 5.4 is already in its [extended phase](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (security fixes only)

Comment: Based on my extremely limited resources, I sadly can't right now.

Comment: What would be the difference between this method and just using `../` as needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67862/discussion-between-axiac-and-firedrake969).