# PHP include path

Tags: php, filepath

I have found a workaround but it does not satisfy me because I don't know why the problem occurs.

On my site I use two scripts: ScriptA.php and ScriptB.php. In ScriptA.php I use

```
$font = 'img/cert/f1.ttf'; // path to font
```

In ScriptB.php this generates an error:

```
PHP Warning:  imagettfbbox(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/vhosts/br-digitalsolutions.eu/httpdocs/partner/scriptB.php
```

So I have to use full the path:

```
$font = '/var/www/vhosts/br-digitalsolutions.eu/httpdocs/partner/img/cert/f1.ttf'; // path to font
```

Comment: Are scriptA and scriptB in the same folder? If not, please update with the folder structure.

Comment: Please provide a clearer description, because the details are obviously important here. What is the path of these two files? What code exactly are you using to `include` and call `imagettfbbox`? You're loosely skipping over some important clarifying context here.

Comment: Take a look at `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. This will always go to the root of your website. This also prevents you from having to type all of the path yourself

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your font like this:

```
$font = "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/partner/img/cert/f1.ttf";
```

You should be able to clear that error out. That is equivalent to `/var/www/vhosts/br-digitalsolutions.eu/httpdocs/partner/img/cert/f1.ttf`.

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is already pointing at `/var/www/vhosts/br-digitalsolutions.eu` so specifying paths this way becomes much easier and less error-prone.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Construct the full path of `'f1.ttf'` from the path of `ScriptA.php` by using function `dirname()` and the magic constant `__DIR__` (or `__FILE__` if you are using a PHP version older than 5.3):

```
$font = __DIR__.'/img/cert/f1.ttf';
```

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680739/php-root-with-htaccess/27680868#27680868) (and the comments) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680739/php-root-with-htaccess).