# Removing file extension apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

today i wanted to achieve this thing where .htaccess automatically removes any sort of file extension from the url on the browser.
Lets say for example user clicks a link to take the user to

mylink.php
It should take him there but remove the .php

i tried using a few .htaccess code but they did not do much.

Also i can access the pages like so

localhost/register << this one works fine but i want the extension to be removed auto

localhost/register/ << this one looses all styling because it behaves like a page in  new folder

The .htaccess code is

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas people?

Comment: *What* `.htaccess` things did you try? Show the actual code that you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [do-it-yourself universal header/footer.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215791/do-it-yourself-universal-header-footer-php)

Comment: i just want it to remove the file extension on its own...

Comment: @Marshall Mathews: So you're not concerned about loosing the style? If not, please remove that part from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Change this to the appropriate base (probably just / in your case)
RewriteBase /stackoverflow/9762238/

# Any url that requests a .php file on the base will be redirected to dir with same base name 
# The condition is important to prevent redirect loops!
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Requests for directories that do not actually exist will be be translated into php file requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [L]
```