# add trailing slash to my urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a serious problem since two days trying to rewrite the urls of my php website with htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule devis demande-devis.php
RewriteRule mentions-legales mentions-legales.php
RewriteRule condition-utilisation condition-utilisation.php
RewriteRule condition-generales-ventes condition-generales-ventes.php
RewriteRule fournisseur fournisseur.php
RewriteRule qui-sommes-nous qui-sommes-nous.php
RewriteRule faq faq.php
RewriteRule services services.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But what I expect for example, is to have `http://www.example.com/services/` .

With the code, when I type that URL into the browsers address bar, I have a web page without CSS.

Comment: There is not enough precise information in that question to give a straight answer. You don't supply the actual result of your rewriting attempts, instead you give a vague mentioning of a probably missing style sheet. And: you refer to "the code below", without actually appending any code.

Comment: http://cars-de-france.com  have a look

Comment: And where is the code in that reply ? Where is the result of the rewriting attempts ? The page loaded at that url loads several styles successfully.

Comment: For the moment my urls are like that because if i add a slash at the end, the page is not well display

Comment: But when I add before the style sheet http://www.domain.com/ everything is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is relative versus absolute notation of the css file urls. 
Consult the http servers error log to see what is actually referenced or check the delivered html source of the page that lacks the style definitions.

The page you specify in your comment to the question shows both, relative and absolute references of css files. However you have no rewriting rules for those...

Comment: you are right! with absolute notation of the css file everything is ok!

Answer (score 0):

That works as usual. Just ensure you set the right link to your CSS files so that the browser is able to request them without 404's from your server.

As you have probably edited the URLs within the .htaccess files after you've written the php script, you need to reflect these changes in your PHP script, too, by updting the links in there, too.

Monitor your server error log to find out which URIs are wrongly send.

Review those.

Then improve the output of your application by fixing that erroneous output.

Please see as well:

- [do-it-yourself universal header/footer.php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9215791/367456)

and similar questions that are about the root of your problem.